# What is the most effective way of making speech synthesizer pronounce the date right?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

I am writing a speech synthesizing program in C#, and I am using two machines for debugging. Machine one has culture name "English (United Kingdom)" and shows the system date as "25/03/2017", machine two has culture name "English (United States)" and shows the system date as "03/25/2017". When using Microsoft David Desktop as a speech synthesizer voice, it pronounces the former as "25 slash 03 slash 2017" and the latter as "25th March 2017". On the other hand, when using Microsoft Hazel Desktop, it pronounces the former as "25th March 2017" and the latter as "03 slash 25 slash 2017". I am aware that Hazel is an English, UK voice and David is an English, US voice. Is there an effective way of making all English voices pronounce the date correctly regardless of whether the system culture is UK or US?

Comment: Have you considered getting rid of the ambiguity by providing the date in words?

Comment: I am using "System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()" to get the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `DateTime.ToLongDateString()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx):
`System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()` gives Friday, 14 April 2017.

This should solve your issue with different speech synthesis voices, however, you must note that the format of the String that you will get from this method will depend on the `CultureInfo` you set.